# chrome extensions : how to completly disable user from installing chrome extensions, such as vpn

Tags: windows, google-chrome, group-policy, brave

I have a home network, I have blocked sites such as youtube,facebook and instagram for my kids, however they are clever to install vpn addons on their chrome and brave users.
How do I completly disable extensions in both brave and chrome

Comment: Are you in control of **how** they run chrome? There is a `--disable-extensions` flag you can add to a shortcut.

Comment: most of the options that work for Chrome/Chromium will work in Brave as well.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes am in control, they are using the local account while I use the admininstrator.